# Show/Hide HTML elements based on their innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the following small piece of Javascript to make a basic calculation from two variable amounts and then display that value using innerHTML My javascript knowledge is limited so I had help putting this together.

```
<script>
 var f = "<?php echo $row_rsFormData['total_flats']; ?>";
 var c = "<?php echo $row_rsCount['count']; ?>";
 var r = Math.round(f / 2) - c
 document.getElementById("remaining").innerHTML = r;
</script>
```

I want to show different elements depending on the value of ' var r'

if var r = 0

I want to display this:

```
<p class="qualify">You have a sufficient amount of leaseholders to qualify for Right to Manage</p>
```

if var r > 0

I want to display this:

```
<p class="count">You need <span id="remaining"></span> more consenting leaseholders to qualify</p>
```

I realise this is simple for most.. so please be kind.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's always interesting to see questions that mix php and js, and at what level people decide to shift their computing from the php to the js.  I mean, the math and the conditional here could all be done in php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't believe this hasn't been answered yet.
As the tags for the question are all client side, I have a client side solution:

```
<script>
 var f = "<?php echo $row_rsFormData['total_flats']; ?>";
 var c = "<?php echo $row_rsCount['count']; ?>";
 var r = Math.round(f / 2) - c
 document.getElementById("remaining").innerHTML = r;
 if(r = 0)
 {
  $('#quality').show();
 }
 if(r > 0)
 {
  $('#count').show();
 }
</script>
```

Add an id attribute to both of your tags:

```
<p id="qualify" class="qualify">You have a sufficient amount of leaseholders to qualify for Right to Manage</p>

<p id="count" class="count">You need <span id="remaining"></span> more consenting leaseholders to qualify</p>
```

And initially hide them in the CSS:

```
#quality, #count
{
 display:none;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Haha! I posted this an a dozen other answers appeared.

AGAIN!

Comment: This appeared to be the simplest solution.. Many thanks #sanepete. although I had to edit (r = 0 ) to (r == 0)

Comment: Doh!

No worries.

Answer (score 1):

You can put `id` attribute in both of these elements and then based on value of `r` , either display/hide either of them.

`

```
<script>
    var f = "<?php echo $row_rsFormData['total_flats']; ?>";
    var c = "<?php echo $row_rsCount['count']; ?>";
    var r = Math.round(f / 2) - c
    document.getElementById("remaining").innerHTML = r;
    r = Number(r);
    if (r == 0) {
        document.getElementById('when0').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('whenlarge0').style.display='none';
    } else if (r > 0) {
        document.getElementById('whenlarge0').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('when0').style.display='none';
    }
</script>
```

`

And your HTML becomes like this :

```
<p id='whenlarge0' class="qualify">You have a sufficient amount of leaseholders to qualify for Right to Manage</p>

<p id='when0' class="count">You need <span id="remaining"></span> more consenting leaseholders to qualify</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I suppose that you don't have both paragraphs yet in your html page.
Using the selector `$('body')`, you can append the paragraph according to the value of `r`.

```
<script>
 var f = "<?php echo $row_rsFormData['total_flats']; ?>";
 var c = "<?php echo $row_rsCount['count']; ?>";
 var r = Math.round(f / 2) - c
 document.getElementById("remaining").innerHTML = r;
 if (r === 0) {
   $('body').append("<p class="qualify">You have a sufficient amount of leaseholders to qualify for Right to Manage</p>")
}
else if(r > 0){
   $('body').append("<p class="count">You need <span id="remaining"></span> more consenting leaseholders to qualify</p>")
}

</script>
```

Comment: Please explain what you have changed, and why it helps solve the problem. Code dump answers do not educate people.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the

tags id and in your javascript code write an if statement to test your conditions, hide or show your

tags:

```
document.getElementById("your_id").style.display = "none"  // to hide
document.getElementById("your_id").style.display = "block" // to show
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer in simple js. Hope it will help you :-)

You have your p tags already prepared and hidden

You will show the right one using style.display
if it is set to "none" it will disappear, if it is set to "block" then it will appear. 
You get sort of pointers to the p tags that are already hidden at load time 
(toRemainder, toQualify ...)
And then you show the right p tag according to the result of the calculation.
A mystery remains : What do you want to do when r < 0 ? ;-)

Figures are random so you can test all the possible ouputs

```js
var f = Math.round(Math.random() * (60 - 50) + 50);
var c = Math.round(Math.random() * (30 - 25) + 25);
var r = Math.round(f / 2) - c
var toRemainder =  document.getElementById("remaining");
var toQualify = document.querySelector(".qualify");
var toCount = document.querySelector(".count");
var toSurprise = document.querySelector(".surprise");

 if(r==0){
  toQualify.style.display = "block";
 }
 else if(r>0){
 toRemainder.innerHTML = r;
 toCount.style.display = "block";
 }
 else{
  toSurprise.style.display = "block";
 }
```

```html
<p class="qualify" style="display:none;">You have a sufficient amount of leaseholders to qualify for Right to Manage</p>
<p class="count" style="display:none;">You need <span id="remaining"></span> more consenting leaseholders to qualify</p>
<p class="surprise" style="display:none;"> r < 0 : What do you want to do here ?</p>
```